# Powershell - Parse web page content

Tags: powershell, parsing

I'm new in powershell / windows scripting and I need to parse a webpage with Invoke-WebRequest, to obtain this text:

```
Version 3.0
```

inside a specific div, with the following href:

```
<a href="/Downloads/IISCrypto/IISCrypto.exe" class="btn-default btn">Download</a>
```

Bellow a example of the web page:

```
<div class="main col-md-12">
    <p class="lead">
        IIS Crypto requires Windows Server 2008 and the .Net 4.0 framework or greater. Both GUI and command line versions are available.
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="box-style-1 gray-bg">
                        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                        <h2>IIS Crypto GUI</h2>
                        <p>Version 3.0 (339 KB)</p>
                        <a href="/Downloads/IISCrypto/IISCrypto.exe" class="btn-default btn">Download</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="box-style-1 gray-bg">
                        <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
                        <h2>IIS Crypto CLI</h2>
                        <p>Version 3.0 (244 KB)</p>
                        <a href="/Downloads/IISCrypto/IISCryptoCli.exe" class="btn-default btn">Download</a>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be answered already, but here you go

```
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest $URL
(($webRequest.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName("box-style-1 gray-bg")[0] | Select-Object innerText) -split ([Environment]::NewLine))[1]
```